# Best way to remove and add elements from the java List

Tags: java

I have 100,000 objects in the list .I want to remove few elements from the list based on condition.Can anyone tell me what is the best approach to achieve interms of memory and performance.

Same question for adding objects also based on condition.

Thanks in Advance
Raju

Comment: We probably need a little more information to support you.

Comment: 1 lakh = 100,000 (according to Wikipedia)

Comment: Is the List sorted? Can it contain duplicates?

Comment: Hi ,yes 100000 objects in java.util.ArrayList.This list doesn't contain duplicates.I want to remove or add objects from existing source list based on condition.

Answer (score 3):

Your container is not just a `List`.  `List` is an interface that can be implemented by, for example `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.  The performance will depend on which of these underlying classes is actually instantiated for the object you are polymorphically referring to as `List`.

`ArrayList` can access elements in the middle of the list quickly, but if you delete one of them you need to shift a whole bunch of elements.  `LinkedList` is the opposite i nthis respect., requiring iteration for the access but deletion is just a matter of reassigning pointers.

Your performance depends on the implementation of `List`, and the best choice of implementation depends on how you will be using the List and which operations are most frequent.

Answer (score 1):

[`Collections2.filter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) (from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)) produces a filtered collection based on a predicate.

```
List<Number> myNumbers = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(1e6));
Collection<Number> bigNumbers = Collections2.filter(
    myNumbers, 
    new Predicate<Number>() {
      public boolean apply(Number n) {
        return n.doubleValue() >= 100d;
      }
    });
```

Note, that some operations like `size()` are not efficient with this scheme.  If you tend to follow Josh Bloch's advice and prefer `isEmpty()` and iterators to unnecessary `size()` checks, then this shouldn't bite you in practice.

Comment: Nitpicking: `Collections2.filter` produces a filtered *view* of another collection, not a *copy* of that collection. As this can be a great source of confusion, you better mention it.

Comment: That's probably a better approach (avoiding homegrown code), regardless of performance.

Comment: @Roland Illig, quite right.  I think Daniel fixed the text.  Depending on what the OPer is doing, `Iterables.filter` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Mike ,Thanks for sample code suppose if i have 100000 employee objects in my source ArrayList say Emp id starts with  1......100000,I have string array contains Emp id's{2,89,100} .So here i will check the id from source list with string array,and removing eleemnts if it matches.I want a better approach to do this.

Comment: @raj, Do you want to do something like
    `for (Iterator<Employee> employeeIt = allEmployees.iterator(); employeeIt.hasNext();) { if (someCondition(employeeIt.next())) { employeeIt.remove(); } }`

Comment: @ColinD, You are right in the worst-case, but in the case where the filter matches most items, and the items it does not match are not clustered at the end, it will be much better in the average case.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah I deleted that comment because I realized my mistake in saying that.

Comment: @Mike: yes like that,but in this case i have to iterate all 100000 elements within the list.is ther any better approach to do as performance wise.

Comment: @raj: I'm not sure what you mean by having to iterate all 100000 elements in the list. _Creating_ this filtered view does not iterate through the list at all! It'll take almost no time. The list won't be iterated until you need or want to iterate through it to do something, and then it'll simply check each element as it goes and skip the ones that don't match the predicate.

Comment: @ColinD,element Means object here,How it will check the condition without iterating  each object  can you provide any example code please.

Comment: @raj: The `Collection` returned by `Collections2.filter` is a filtered live view of the `Collection` it's given... the condition is checked _lazily_ when you iterate through its elements. It just skips ones that don't match the condition.

Comment: Won't `isEmpty()` also have to iterate the whole list and therefore be just as inefficient as `size()`?

Comment: @Software Monkey: No, `isEmpty()` can (and does) stop and return false as soon as it finds a single element that matches the predicate.

Comment: @Colin: Unless the filtered list actually is empty (or it's only elements are few and near the end of the basing list).

Comment: Hi Guys,I dont understand which api your talking about,if anyone have atleast provide some sample code,that will help to understand betterly.

Comment: @raj: Yeah that could have been made more clear I suppose. `Collections2.filter` and the `Predicate` interface it uses are both from [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com).

Comment: @Software Monkey: Yes, of course, but in general `isEmpty()` may perform significantly better than `size()`, as `size()` _must_ check all elements of the source collection while `isEmpty()` can check as few as a single element.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be iterating a list and applying tests to each element, then a `LinkedList` will be most efficient in terms of CPU time, because you don't have to shift any elements in the list. It will, however consume more memory than an `ArrayList`, because each list element is actually held in an entry.

However, it might not matter. 100,000 is a small number, and if you aren't removing a lot of elements the cost to shift an `ArrayList` will be low. And if you are removing a lot of elements, it's probably better to restructure as a copy-with filter.

However, the only real way to know is to write the code and benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

**LinkedList** could be a good choice.

LinkedList does "*remove and add elements*" more effective than ArrayList. and no need to call such method as `ArrayList.trimToSize()` to remove useless memory. But LinkedList is a dual-linked list, each element is wrapped as an Entry which needs extra memory.